# How to toggle the case of individual words in sentences displayed in HTML form input boxes by double clicking them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, field, coldfusion-11

Double clicking a word in a sentence in an HTML form input box will highlight that word. I want each double click to toggle the case of the highlighted word between lower and upper case.

```
    <input id="vnib" type="text" value="#ATitle#">
```

Example: the title showing in the input box is "The longest Day".
When I double click on the word "longest" it will change to "Longest".

Why this? I need to correct hundreds of capitalization errors in a list of 30,000 titles and want to save hundreds of key presses. Right now I have to select the initial letters of each incorrectly capitalized word and then type in the letters with the correct case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple HTML + pure JS solution.

```js
let content = document.getElementById("content");
content.addEventListener("dblclick", changeSelectionCase);
function changeSelectionCase(e) {
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection && selection.rangeCount > 0) {
    let selectionRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    let startOffset = selectionRange.startOffset
    content.textContent = content.textContent.substring(0, startOffset) +
                          content.textContent[startOffset].toUpperCase() +
                          content.textContent.substring(startOffset + 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nostrum optio suscipit cumque adipisci molestias inventore officia ea corrupti dolore alias nemo iure, beatae porro soluta quo aliquam ut facere.</p>
```

@Commata, per your comments, made it easier. Just save the below code as an HTML file and open it up with your browser. It contains an editable paragraph, so you can copy/paste your text on it. Then double click on the words you want to toggle the case of the first letter.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        p:before {
            content: "(Paste content here)";
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 1rem;
        }
        p {
            margin: 2rem;
            padding: 2rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p contenteditable="true" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nostrum
        optio suscipit cumque adipisci molestias inventore officia ea corrupti dolore alias nemo iure, beatae porro
        soluta quo aliquam ut facere.</p>
</body>
<script>
    let content = document.getElementById("content");
    content.addEventListener("dblclick", changeSelectionCase);
    function changeSelectionCase(e) {
        let selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection && selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            let selectionRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            let startOffset = selectionRange.startOffset;
            let upperCase = content.textContent[startOffset].toUpperCase();
            let toggledCase = upperCase === content.textContent[startOffset]
                ? content.textContent[startOffset].toLowerCase()
                : content.textContent[startOffset].toUpperCase();
            content.textContent = content.textContent.substring(0, startOffset) +
                toggledCase +
                content.textContent.substring(startOffset + 1);
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I am getting a response of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')". Grateful for the suggestion but I do not have the skills to troubleshoot.

Comment: Now I noticed your Lore ipsum, and that works very well.
I shall now try to find out what differences in my source code might be causing the problem.

Comment: Finally, I need for the code to toggle the case. Your example changes from lower to upper but not from upper to lower.

Comment: @Commata, just saw your comments and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Burkay, your code works with your paragraph:
<p contenteditable="true" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nostrum etc. etc.</p>
but my text is in an input box :

<p contenteditable="true" id="content"><input id="vnib" type="text" name="ATitle" value="The longest Day"></p>

and is unaffected by the changeSelectionCase code.

Comment: @Commata, unfortunately getSelection does not work with inputs. Does it have to be an input? If your purpose is just to correct your text, why does it matter?

Comment: with a few thousand errors in 31,000 records I save several hours of time by double-clicking once  instead of first selecting the character with the mouse and then typing the letter (or Shift + the letter) on the keyboard. I'm going to keep trying to somehow reset the value of the input text with Javascript.

Comment: I see your point and you can totally do that with the approach in the answer. You do not need to use an input tag, you can use that paragraph as an input since it has contenteditable=true. Open the HTML with browser, select and delete the lorem ipsum part, paste your text and start double clicking :)

Comment: OK, I will try it — convert the titles field with 31,000 records from the MS Access database into a text file, enclose it in P tags and double-click away. Convert back to Access and all should be well!